# How to prevent this android building message with shakebugs ScreenRecordingService tagged at AndroidManifest about a declaration?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, shake

As a result of building an android app, I have got a strange message - at least for me -:

> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest
> ...\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:39:9-43:36 Warning:
> service#com.shakebugs.shake.internal.shake.recording.ScreenRecordingService was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:39 to replace another declaration but no other declaration present

Declarations and usages of shakebbugs are pretty simple in the java code of the app

Gradle (Project)

```
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        // https://www.shakebugs.com/docs/android/setup/
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/shakebugs/shake' }
    } }
```

Gradle (:app)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.test"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
    }
dependencies {
    // Shake Bugs
    implementation 'com.shakebugs:shake:14.1.3'
}
```

AppClass.java

```
import com.shakebugs.shake.Shake;
public class AppClass extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Timber.d("Init Shake");
        Shake.start(this, "my-nice-api-client-id", "my-cool-api-client-secret");

    }
}
```

What's going wrong according to you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the support of shakebugs.com, I understood that

- Warning was in fact for manifest of sdk shakebugs.com
- Don't worry with this warning
- This warning will disappear with a future release of shakebugs

Thanks !

Comment: No more build warning with release 14.3.0 of shakebugs